# what is the benefit to create a singleton class by implementing a interface?

Tags: c#

if I have a interface like below,

```
 public interface IMethods
  {
    void M1();
    void M2();
  }
```

then I want to create a singleton class by inheriting above interface, then what's the benefit in context of re use of singleton class and how?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you're asking "what's the benefit of implementing this interface as a singleton" the answer is the same benefit that singleton always offers: "a guarantee of one instance no matter how many places it's used". Singleton exists to enforce a single instance of a class with instance access vs static class and methods/properties. An example implementation:

```
public class Methods : IMethods
{
    // Singleton instance
    private static readonly IMethods _instance = new Methods();

    // Private constructor to enforce singleton
    private Methods()
    {

    }

    // The instance getter
    public static IMethods Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public void M1()
    {

    }

    public void M2()
    {

    }
}
```

The thing that will hose you here is the fact that the `Instance` property is not exposed on the `IMethods` interface, so getting it requires the instance type to be `Methods` and not `IMethods` which sort of defeats the purpose of the inheriting the interface.

Often, people use dependency injection frameworks to set the lifetime of an interface's implementation to singleton AKA shared instance instead. It is more "OO friendly".

Comment: Access to the `Instance` property can be hidden behind a `MethodsFactory` that knows about the singleton, but returns an `IMethods`. As you say, this is usually given for free by most DI containers.

Comment: Good point @AdamHouldsworth, hadn't considered that. Still, more tightly coupled than a DI framework.

Comment: No more coupled than a DI framework, you're either coupled to your `MethodsFactory` or your Ninject `kernel.Get<IMethods>()`. All things can be abstracted equally, DI just gives you extra stuff for free as opposed to the poor man's approach.

Comment: True enough. Depends if you properly apply IoC or not I guess.

Comment: Well, properly applying IoC has nothing to do with using frameworks, so I still stand by the comment that using a framework doesn't give you any more loose coupling than you can achieve yourself.

Comment: Well, properly applying IoC has lots to do with using frameworks: it determines whether or not one class is coupled to your framework or ALL of them are. :) I do fully agree with your comment re: DI vs factory - both couple identically.

Comment: Applying IoC doesn't *need* a framework (yes, it *can* have lots to do with it, but it doesn't *need* to), you just tend to use one because you get other stuff that you'd otherwise need to do yourself. Properly also depends on the scale of which you need to abstract your dependencies etc. I'm just getting pedantic over the argument that a framework is needed.

Comment: I disagree with you, but since this is off-topic to OP's question, let's leave it at that for now. :)

Answer (score 3):

The singleton aspect is just one implementation of the `IMethods` contract, giving you the benefit of the singleton pattern, assuming that is what you need.

The benefit of exposing that singleton through an interface is that the consumer doesn't need to care how it is implemented, just that it *is* implemented and they can use it. At a later date if you suddenly need a regular instance as opposed to a singleton, you can change that without impacting consumers.

<sup>This happens very frequently with DI containers, where you can usually configure the lifecycle of a binding to be in singleton scope.</sup>

If you use the singleton directly and never really use the interface, then there is little use in the interface. If the singleton is being used without really needing to constrain it to a single instance, then there is little use in adopting the singleton pattern.

Comment: could you please please post some sample code real time scenario?

Comment: No need really, it would be a standard singleton implementation that happens to also implement your interface. The extra bit would be using a DI container or the factory pattern for returning `IMethods`.